# Ubuntu upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 [which is not the latest release]

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.04, versions

Is it possible to upgrade to version 15.04,

This is not the latest released version. Current version being one of 16x.

I want to do this since patch for AMD Radeon is not available yet. I do not want to try open source drivers.

Comment: depending on you exact radeon card, you might try the OSS driver in 16.04 anyways, as the new closed driver need the anyways. as part of the driver chain.

Comment: If you are on 14.04, it would be pointless to upgrade to anything but16.04. 15.04 is unsupported since quite some time, and 15.10 will be in a few weeks. Better stay on 14.04 for now.

Comment: If upgrading is just for the general sake of upgrading, stay on 14.04 given your hardware. If you are trying to get a newer version of a particular package, there may be ways to get that newer version on 14.04. It depends on several factors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to  update your reprosties to update to  a newer ubuntu version.

but do not update to 15.04 as it is no longer mantained. you have to upgrade to at least 15.10 to still get security fixes.

Fully fleshed out answer comes later, when I or some editor has the commands for CLI and GUI at hand.

Comment: 15.10 goes EOL this month.

Comment: thanks, so for real uptdate stays only 16.04 atm, which has´t a update AMDs closed source driver yet, and probaly will never get it for older card pre GCN 1.1 anyway.

Comment: That sums it up, yes.